# Philips Hue API: Turn on lights at fix time

Tags: philips-hue

I'm programming on HUE API.I want to schedule for a light turn on at one time and automatically turn off at another time. As this link is for reference (you must login before see this page).
[HUE API Schedules API](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/schedules-api-0)

As I research, maybe noway for me to do that except I must separate to two schedule commands: schedule to turn on at one time and schedule to turn off at another time.

Is this true way to done this work ? Because I see that is too handy. Is there another way for HUE API does automatically ? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best way would be to create two schedules. I also think it might be the only way.

Here is a command to turn on all your lights at 09:00

```
{
    "command": {
        "address": "/api/<username>/groups/0/action",
        "body": {
            "on": true
        },
        "method": "PUT"
    },
    "time": "W127/T09:00:00"
}
```

Remember to replace `<username>`. The time I specified here means "every day of the week at 09:00 UTC". Note that the time is UTC, not your local time.

The link that explains time patterns is currently broken in the Schedules API page. Here is a fixed link for you: [Datatypes and Time Patterns](http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/datatypes-and-time-patterns)

You might also want to read this for more explanation on time patterns: [Recurring schedules](http://www.everyhue.com/vanilla/discussion/334/recurring-schedules/p1)

Comment: Hello, does W127 mean for each day of the week or for each weekday? If not, how to make it for each day? Thnx

Answer (score 4):

To answer Booharin above, W127 is the binary encoding for the days of the week that the schedule runs. Monday = 64, Tuesday = 32, Wednesday = 16, Thursday = 8, Friday = 4, Saturday = 2, Sunday = 1.  If you want your schedule to run only on workdays, the value would be W124. (64+32+16+8+4 = 124) The API specifies 3 numbers, so a schedule that runs on Monday would be W064.

Answer (score 2):

I can't seem to directly comment to the other answer (not enough points) so trying this.

You can use your local time by using "localtime" instead of "time". This was added in a bridge update at the beginning of 2014. Note that this requires the timezone of the bridge to be configured.